# Right way to do implement customView with map

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to create `UITableView` with map in beginning. Like in Foursquare app:

[image]

The trick is after scroll map should disappear like that:

[image]

How to do it? I'm thinking about using scrollview under the TableView, but maybe is a better solution. This can be done in interface builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your map view as `UITableView`s `tableHeaderView`. It will then scroll with tables content like in your screenshot

Short basic example code:

```
CGFloat mapHeight = 100.0f;
MKMapView *mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, mapHeight)];
//  Do additional configurations of map view
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = mapView;
```

This code added to `-(void)viewDidLoad` will add 100pts in height`MKMapView` to the top of `UITableViewController`s table view